# wget not doing anything

Tags: shell, wget

I've got a Raspberry Pi running some Python/Flask scripts.  There are 2 routes that do the following:

1. Check bluetooth connections in the house to see if anyone is home and write the result to a MySQL table.
2. Check the result of the above every 15 minutes.  If the house is empty, turn off the central heating.

I have 2 shell scripts that apply to the above:

occupancy.sh

```
wget -O - http://mydomain.co.uk/occupancy  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

heatadjust.sh

```
wget -O - http://mydomain.co.uk/heatingadjust  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Permissions and ownership are the same on both files.

These both run from crontab - they both show up in syslog but crontab looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/html/dashboard/dashboard/occupancy.sh
*/5 * * * * /var/www/html/dashboard/dashboard/heatadjust.sh
```

Option 1 just works.  Does exactly what it should.

Option 2 doesn't work.  If I run the wget from the command line without sending it to /dev/null it responds with a 200 status and no errors.  Nothing in the error log.  Apache access shows the hit.

Nothing in the script actually happens though.

If I run the shell script from the command line, again, nothing happens and no errors that I can find.

BUT... If I paste the address into the browser, it works perfectly.

Has anyone got any idea on where I can look next?

Comment: Doesn't `wget -O - ...`  mean "output to `stdout`?  Which you immediately throw away with `... > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: You can check the server side like access log? to make sure the request is sent and received.

Comment: AndrewHenle - Quite possibly.  I'm very knowledgable about this stuff and got the example from somewhere else.  All I know is that I want it to silently do the job and it seems to work.

shingo - I've done that.  The script is called if I look at /var/log/syslog and the URL is called if I look in /var/log/apache2/access.log.

The weird thing is that if I put the wget for heatingadjust into the occupancy file then it doesn't work.  It only works when I put the URL into the browser.  If it wasn't for the fact that the occupancy route works in the same file, I'd think it was permissions

Comment: If the request is received by the server side, the problem maybe inside the server handler/script, eg. it checks UA, content type ... before the main works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.  The problem isn't directly with wget, it's the fact that my Python script relies on reading a session variable I've set with an authentication token for the Hive API.  What I've had to do for the moment is add in the authentication at the start of my script so that it get a new token from Hive every time that it runs.

I'm sure there's a more elegant way round this but a lot of what I've already written relies on the same authentication check function so I'll need to think of a different way of doing it.